# Is it possible to get source code from SAS view table?

Tags: view, sas

I have a functioning SAS view table, but the source code which creates this view is lost.
Is it possible to extract it directly from the view file itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many views in SAS are created with PROC SQL. Datastep view are very uncommon. So DESCRIBE VIEW might work.

```
proc sql;
  describe view VIEWNAME;
quit;
```

NOTE: the view code will be written to log

Comment: Why do you assert data step view is "very uncommon".

Comment: oh - ha ha, I just assumed it was a data step view!

Comment: I used SAS for twenty in different companies years but never seen any datastep view in production Environment.

Comment: @lee It's very workplace-dependent. E.g. at my workplace use of `proc sql` is actively discouraged and data step views are much more common.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try:

```
data view = myview;
describe;
run;
```

This is more likely to work if you run it on the same system where `myview` was originally created.

Comment: I get this errror "ERROR: The view TEST12.MAINEVALUATION is either corrupt or not a DATA step view." So very likely this view is created with PROC SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty but you could read the definition from the binary view file itself.

See the following example:

```
data myview /view=myview;
set sashelp.class;
x=age;
height=age*x;
run;

data _null_;
infile "%sysfunc(pathname(work))/myview.sas7bvew";
input;
put _infile_;
run;
```

Which gives the below in the log:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for idea. I got 400+ lines of barely readable text. Maybe with some patience :)

Comment: yep, the describe statement (for datastep or the sql version) was indeed the correct answer, I learned something new today!

Answer (score 1):

```
DESCRIBE; 
Without Arguments 

Use the DESCRIBE statement to retrieve program source code from a stored compiled DATA step program or a DATA step view. SAS writes the source statements to the SAS log. 

25   data v / view=v;
26      set sashelp.class;
27      if sex eq 'F';
28      run;

NOTE: DATA STEP view saved on file WORK.V.
NOTE: A stored DATA STEP view cannot run under a different operating system.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


29
30   data view=v;
31      describe;
32      run;

NOTE: DATA step view WORK.V is defined as:

data v / view=v;
   set sashelp.class;
   if sex eq 'F';
run;
```